# Is Google App Engine secure enough for financial applications?

Tags: security, google-app-engine, money

I am wondering whether Google App Engine is secure enough for financial applications? This would involve storing sensitive information, access to users' funds, etc. Are there any applications like that already running on App Engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How much do you trust Google with your information, passwords, and financial data?

It's like other company's that offer this type of service for people. If you think you can trust Google, and their security standards, I see nothing wrong with using the App Engine to host the financial application.

From the [Google Enterprise](http://googleenterprise.blogspot.com/2011/08/security-first-google-apps-and-google.html) Blog Article:

> Since 2008, Google Apps has successfully undergone annual SAS 70 Type II audits. This year the SAS70 Type II audit has evolved into the SSAE 16 Type II attestation and its international counterpart, ISAE 3402 Type II. We’re happy to announce that Google is one of the first major cloud providers to be certified for compliance to these new audit standards.

I strongly believe that will meet the standards to keep financial information secure.